# emailjs: ECONNREFUSED

Tags: javascript, node.js, smtp

I would like to send e-mail from within a node app on my development server for testing purposes (running macOS 10.11.6). I can send e-mail from the command line like this:

```
$ date | mail -s testing my@email.address
```

I am trying to use `emailjs`, which seems to be fairly standard, however I get an ECONNREFUSED error. I can not find out why the connection is not succesful, any hints on additional debug information?

```
const email = require('emailjs')
const smtp = email.server.connect({
  user: process.env.SMTP_USER,
  password: process.env.SMTP_PASSWORD,
  host: process.env.SMTP_HOST,
  ssl: !!process.env.SMTP_ENABLE_SSL
})
smtp.send({
    from: 'noreply@localhost',
    to: recipient,
    subject: 'Test subject',
    text: 'Hello world'
  }, err => err ? console.error('Error when sending mail', err) : done()
)
```

The log output looks like this:

```
Error when sending mail { Error: connection encountered an error
    at module.exports (/code/server/node_modules/emailjs/smtp/error.js:3:13)
    at TLSSocket.error (/code/server/node_modules/emailjs/smtp/response.js:26:29)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1281:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
  code: 5,
  previous: 
   { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:465
       at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
       at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1049:20)
       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1090:14)
     code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
     errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
     syscall: 'connect',
     address: '127.0.0.1',
     port: 465 },
  smtp: undefined }
```

Is this a configuration issue with `postfix`? I use the standard config and `mail` is smart enough to work it out. How do I find the default credentials? Thanks in advance!

Comment: And do you have an email server installed, that answers on port 465 ?

Comment: `postfix` is running, which, according to various guides can be used for that on a standard macOS installation, or am I getting something wrong? And the `mail` executable somehow sends its mails, even though `netstat -an | grep 'LISTEN' | grep 465` does not return anything.